# Get data from an entity

Tags: angular, ngrx

I've a lot of problems to show entities data in the page. I've found a solution. I use the ids array created by the entity, however I'm not really satisfied by this solution, do you have a better way to show entity datas?

I used the ids array to extract the data, but I would like to access directly the entities.

Where I'm wrong?

Sorry if I look very naive.

Thanks for your times

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-2">

        </div>
            <div class="purple text-center" ><i class="material-icons md-64">home</i> <span class="titleForm" *ngIf="!buildings.loading">Your Properties</span></div>
            <div *ngIf="(buildings | async).error" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible text-center" color="primary">
                <strong>Error!</strong> Please Check your Internet connect or Try to reaload the page, if the problem persist please contact Us
            </div>
            <mat-spinner *ngIf="buildings.loading"></mat-spinner>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let i = index, let id of (buildings|async).ids" >
                <mat-expansion-panel color="accent" *ngIf="!buildings.loading" >
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                      <mat-panel-title color="accent" >
                        <h4 class="textWarn"><i class="material-icons">home</i> {{ (buildings | async).entities[(buildings | async).ids[i]].nameBuilding}}</h4>
                      </mat-panel-title>
                    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <div >
                        <p >{{(buildings | async).entities[(buildings | async).ids[i]].address}}</p>
                        <p >{{(buildings | async).entities[(buildings | async).ids[i]].info}}</p>

                        <section class="text-right">
                          <div class="row text-center">
                            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                              <div class="col-md-4">
                                  <button mat-raised-button class="text-center" type="submit" color="primary">View Rooms</button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-2">
                                  <button mat-raised-button class="text-center" type="submit" color="primary" [routerLink]="['/dashboard/new-room/', (buildings | async).ids[i]]" >New Room</button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-2">
                                  <button mat-raised-button class="text-center" type="submit" color="accent" [routerLink]="['/dashboard/edit-building/', (buildings | async).ids[i]]"
                                  routerLinkActive="router-link-active" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">Edit</button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-2">
                                  <button mat-raised-button class="text-center" color="warn" (click)="onDelete()">Delete {{ (buildings | async).ids[i] }}</button>
                              </div>

                          </div>
                        </section>
                      </div>

                  </mat-expansion-panel>
            </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'd like to use something like

```js
entities.nameBuilding instead of (buildings | async).entities[(buildings | async).ids[i]].nameBuilding
```

here the ts file, I used a selector to select the part that contain my entities.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { StorageDataService } from 'src/app/shared/storage-data.service';
import { Building } from 'src/app/shared/models/building.model';


// import * as fromBuildings from '../store/building-list.reducer';
import * as fromIndexReducer from '../../../../reducers/index';
import * as fromBuildings from '../store/building-list.reducer';
import * as buildingsAction from '../store/building-list.actions';
import {selectAllBuildings} from '../store/building-list.selectors';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-building',
  templateUrl: './list-building.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-building.component.css']
})
export class ListBuildingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private storageData: StorageDataService,
    private store: Store<fromBuildings.BuildingsState>
              ) {}

  buildings$: Observable<any>;
  buildings: any;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildings$ = this.store.select<fromBuildings.BuildingsState>('buildings');
    // this.store.select<fromBuildings.BuildingsState>
    // this.buildings$ = this.store.select<fromBuildings.AppState[]>('statusList');
    this.buildings = this.buildings$;

    this.store.dispatch(new buildingsAction.LoadingBuildings());
    // console.log('buildings', this.buildings.source);
  }
  onDelete(id: string) {
    this.storageData.deleteBuilding(id);
  }


}
```

Comment: It would help us a lot if you would break down your code to the parts that are really necessary.

Comment: Also please add the interface BuildiungsState

Comment: @Joniras import { Building} from './building.model';

export interface Buildings {
  _id: string;
  building: Building;
}

Comment: @Joniras in the end I want something like (buildings | async).buildings. if I add to the state buildings with the payload I can I access in this way and after use building.nameBuilding building._id building.address and building.info, with the entity I can't do it

Comment: I dont really get the thing with the Ids. please add the info to the question. Also add the BuildiungsState Interface

Answer (score 1):

I fix it, in order to do so, I created a pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'entities'})
export class Entities implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, arg: any = null): any {

    return Object.values(value);

    // .map(key => value[key]);
    }
}
```

after I've queried directly the entities

```
let building of (buildings|async).entities | entities
```

That's it, I know that It was simple, thanks for your help!

Comment: actually the selectAll selector of the entityAdapter provides an array of all entities, thats the purpose of it. You import a selector but don't use it. With this line `this.buildings$ = this.store.select<fromBuildings.BuildingsState>('buildings');` you just select your featureState but not the buildings within this featureState. That is why you get an object. Selectors are chained functions to extract pieces down the state. You do the same now with a pipe and object property access. Here is a good article about how selectors work: https://toddmotto.com/ngrx-store-understanding-state-selectors

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've to say that I tried with a selector, I've tried this.buildings$ = this.store.select<fromBuildings.BuildingsState>('entities') and this.buildings$ = this.store.select<fromBuildings.BuildingsState>(data => data.entities.buildings) but with any luck, however I thought about it almost all the night, in the end with a pipe you can read all object without select it, it's not so bad. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If `buildins.entities` is an array you can iterate over it like this:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let i = index, let building of (buildings|async).entities" >
    {{building.building.name}}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, there is a reason why did you use the double dot?

Comment: Just to say, entities is not an array, it's an object actually

Comment: @Jiniras I fix it, in order to do so, I created a pipe

    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Pipe({name: 'entities'})
    export class Entities implements PipeTransform {
      transform(value: any, arg: any = null): any {
    
        return Object.values(value);
    
        // .map(key => value[key]);
        }
    }

after I've queried directly the entities

    let building of (buildings|async).entities | entities 

That's it, I know that It was simple, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the entity adapter you have built in selectors:

```
export const { selectIds, selectEntities, selectAll, selectTotal } = adapter.getSelectors();
```

You can use them in your component:

```
buildings$: Observable<any> = this.store.select(selectAll);
```

then in html part:

```
<div *ngFor="let building of buildings$ | async">
building.name 
</div>
```

Return types of selectors are:

```
selectIds: string[] | number[]
selectEntities: Dictionary<T> (it is like a map just use: buldings[key])
selectAll: Buldings[]; (normal array of your entity type)
selectTotal: number
```

**EDIT:**

I think your problem is within the selector logic. When you want to access your feature state, you need to create a feature selector, then you can use the adapter to select the entities:

```
//create feature selector
export const getBuildingsState= createFeatureSelector('buildings');

//select entities calling feature selector first
export const getBuildings = createSelector(
getBuildingsState,
adapter.selectAll
)
```

Finally in component:

```
this.store.select(getBuildings)
```

Also your state should look like this:

```
export interface BuildingsState extends EntityState<Buildings> {
  loading: boolean;
  logged: boolean;
  error: boolean;
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Buildings> = createEntityAdapter<Buildings>(
  { selectId: buildings => buildings._id }
);

export const initialState: BuildingsState = adapter.getInitialState({
  loading: false,
  logged: true,
  error: false
});
```

Comment: doesn't work it's still an object I can't access, This was my first solution, You cant access directly the entity un need to select the id before entering the data like in a simple array, here the structor

Comment: export interface BuildingsState extends EntityState<Buildings> {
  buildings: Building[];
  building: any;
  loading: boolean;
  logged: boolean;
  error: boolean;
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Buildings> =
  createEntityAdapter<Buildings>({selectId: buildings => buildings._id});


export const initialState: BuildingsState = adapter.getInitialState({

  buildings: [],
  ids: [],
  entities: {},
  building: null,
  loading: false,
  logged: true,
  error: false
});

Comment: export function BuildingsReducers(state: BuildingsState = initialState, action): BuildingsState {
  switch (action.type) {
    
    case BuildingsActionTypes.LoadingBuildingsSuccess: {

      const loading = false;
      const logged = true;
      const error = false;
      const buildings = action.payload;

      return adapter.addAll(action.payload,
        {
        ...state,
        loading,
        logged,
        error,
        buildings,
        });
    }

Comment: as I show in the code (buildings | async).entities[(buildings | async).ids[i]].address this is working, I access the address value, but I'm sure I can do it in a simplest way

Comment: You don't have to add buildings to BuildingsState as it extends `EntityState<Buildings>`. The super class already provides these attributes: `ids: string[] | number[]; entities: Dictionary<T>;` entities is what you want to access they represent your buildings

Comment: I add buildings just to check that it works, if i navigate trow it as array works perfectly, the problem is that entities is an object, maybe I need to map it before? I know that out there there is a super easy solution, but I can't catch it since 4/6 hrs

Comment: this is not the problem, I've a selector, you can see that I've imported it in the top. The problems is not to get data but access to it. Datas are in state, I access it via  (buildings | async).entities[(buildings | async).ids[i]].address as I said, the selector doesn't turn an object into an array

Comment: I fix it, in order to do so, I created a pipe

    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Pipe({name: 'entities'})
    export class Entities implements PipeTransform {
      transform(value: any, arg: any = null): any {
    
        return Object.values(value);
    
        // .map(key => value[key]);
        }
    }

after I've queried directly the entities

    let building of (buildings|async).entities | entities 

That's it, I know that It was simple, thanks for your help!